# Azure SignalR Notifications from Service Bus Qeue

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-signalr

We have a Service Bus queue that handles multiple message topics/subscriptions and what we'd like to be able to do is when certain messages have been handled is to notify connected users that a message has been handled.
The message handling takes place in a simple console app but we're not sure how to create a connection to our Azure SignalR service and send a message once it's been processed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest most scalable approach would be to have a simple azure function to do this.

You would just have to use the [Service Bus Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger) which runs your function when a message arrives and use the [SignalR Service Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service#signalr-output-binding) to send the message to your users.

Your function could be as simple as the following

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem,
    [SignalR(HubName = "chat")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages
    ILogger log)
{
    return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
        new SignalRMessage 
        {
            Target = "newMessage", 
            Arguments = new [] { myQueueItem } 
        });
}
```